# Conditions on factorization

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is the only simplification of

$$ \alpha x^2 + \alpha y^2 + \alpha z^2 + 2xy + 2yz + 2xz \tag{1} $$

this: 
$$ (x+y+z)^2 \tag{2} $$
when $\alpha=1$. In other words, if $\alpha\neq 1$, is there any way I can write (1) in some form similar to (2), up to some multiple appearing somewhere in the binomial form? I'm not sure if this question falls under the number theory tag, but I'll put it there for now. Thanks!

Comment: There is $(\alpha-1)(x^2+y^2+z^2) +(x+y+z)^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial is symmetric in $x,y,z$ so it can be expressed in terms of the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $e_1=\sum_{cyc} x$, $e_2=\sum_{cyc} xy$, $e_3=\sum_{cyc}xyz$. It turns out that the representation is:

$$\alpha x^2 + \alpha y^2 + \alpha z^2 + 2xy + 2yz + 2xz = \alpha e_1^2 + 2(1 - \alpha)e_2$$

The only case where this reduces to a function in $e_1=x+y+z$ alone is $\alpha = 1$.

Other than that, chances for a simple factorization are slim to none. Consider for example the case of $2$ variables, where $\alpha x^2 + \alpha y^2 + 2xy$ has no "nice" closed form except for $\alpha = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

somewhat depends what coefficients you allow. With
$$ \omega = -\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt 3}{2},   $$
$$ \left( x + \omega y + \omega^2 z \right)\left( x + \omega^2 y + \omega z \right) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - yz - zx - xy  $$